# ASP.NET MVC Razor Concatenation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying the render an HTML list that looks like the following, using the Razor view engine:

```
<ul>
  <li id="item_1">Item 1</li>
  <li id="item_2">Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

The code that I am attempting to use to render this list is:

```
<ul>
@foreach (var item in Model.TheItems)
{            
  <li id="item_@item.TheItemId">Item @item.TheItemId</li>
}
</ul>
```

The parser is choking, because it thinks that that everything to the right of the underscore in the id attribute is plain text and should not be parsed.  I'm uncertain of how to instruct the parser to render TheItemId.

I don't want to but a property on the model object that includes the item_ prefix.

I also have to keep this syntax as I am using the list with JQuery Sortable and with the serialize function that requires the id attribute to be formatted in this syntax.

Answer (score 218, accepted):

You should wrap the inner part of the call with `( )`:

```
<li id="item_@(item.TheItemId)">
```

Comment: I started with String.Format but prefer the syntax and brevity of your response, I'm marking it as my preferred answer.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and ASP.NET MVC 5, and this is not working (the string is set *as is*, including the `@` and the parentheses)... What finally worked for me was the very ungraceful `id="foo" + Model.Bar`.

Comment: This gave me the variable in parenthesis. It appears that Razor now understands that an underscore + a variable = a string + a variable.

Answer (score 27):

How about using [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.71).aspx)? like this:

`<li id="@String.Format("item_{0}", item.TheItemId)">`

Comment: This is not parsing correctly, due to nested double-quotes... should the inner quotes be single-quotes and the outer double-quotes, something like `id="@String.Format('foo{0}', item.Bar)"`?

Answer (score 12):

I prefer:

```
<li id="@String.Concat("item_", item.TheItemId)">
```

The verbosity tells the support developers exactly what is happening, so it's clear and easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

You can even use this way to **concat more strings**:

```
<li id="@("item-"+item.Order + "item_"+item.ShopID)" class="ui-state-default"></li>
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10443148/2218697) is another post.

Hope helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can so this in a simpler way:

```
id="item_@item.TheItemId"
```

Answer (score 0):

This post seems to be older  but now this does works now in latest MVC:

```
id="item_@item.TheItemId"
```