# How to concatenate the id of the HTML element using Razor ASp.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a grid column with checkboxes and I want to give them a different id. Id is based on the CustomerId in the Model. What syntax should I use to concatenate the chk_@item.CustomerId.

```
// using the telerik grid 
id="chk_@item.OrderNumber"  // does not work
```

// this will put the value of @item.Customernumber as the checkbox id

```
columns.Template(@<text><input type='checkbox' id="@item.Customernumber" name="@item.CustomerNumber" value="@item.OrderNumber" /></text>).Width(50)
```

second option:

```
columns.Template(@<text><input type='checkbox' id="chk_@item.Customernumber" name="@item.CustomerNumber" value="@item.OrderNumber" /></text>).Width(50)
```

the above will render as

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk_@item.Customernumber" value=... />
```

Comment: How do you conclude "does not work", what is happening. From the code you post, I cannot see if this is from your View or controller. Post just a little more (wrapping {} or <tag> would be nice to get the context).

Comment: @johndoe, the answer sorts the issue out. could you mark it as answer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671086/is-there-a-way-to-concatenate-strings-in-html-attributes

Answer (score 48):

`chk_@item.OrderNumber` will not work because razor thinks of it as of an e-mail, you need to do it like this instead: `chk_@(item.OrderNumber)`

Comment: it appends '(' as well in data

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702957/asp-net-mvc-razor-concatenation/) is another post, hope helps someone.

Answer (score 34):

Correct Syntax

```
id="@("chk_"+@item.Id)"
```

Answer (score 0):

This does works now in latest MVC:

```
id="chk_@item.OrderNumber"
```

Happy coding.