# Is there a way to concatenate strings in html attributes?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using MVC3 and I wanted to use a partial view to create dynamic DOM elements. This is my current partial view:

```
@model MVCApp.ViewModels.TitlesViewModel

<div class="display-label">Name</div>
<div id="label"+"@Model.Id" class="display-field">@Model.InitValue</div>
```

Model.Id is 1 but in the HTML in the browser, I currently get:

```
id="label"+"1"
```

So if I try and do something like:

```
alert($("#label1").text())
```

There's an alert box with nothing in it.

So how can I add the two strings together to form one coherent string that is recognized by jQuery (or document.getElementByID(str) for that matter).

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Try this (verified):

```
<div id="@("label"+Model.Id)" class="display-field">@Model.InitValue</div>
```

Comment: This worked:  `<div id="@("label"+Model.Id)" class="display-field">@Model.InitValue</div>`  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Added quotes just now (while you're posting your comment) :)

Comment: Yeah, I saw. Thanks for the help, though. I'm still new to MVC3 and Razor syntax.

Answer (score 4):

You want:

```
<div id="label@Model.Id" ...
```

Razor will recognise the @ as the start of code, execute it and render the results in place in the attribute.

Edit:

This didn't work well as a comment, but here's a line from one of my Razor controls:

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" 
       class="display-field display-field-@ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName" 
       id="@((ViewData["id"] == null) ? 
         ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName : ViewData["id"])"
       value="@Proj.GetJobStatusValue(Model)" />
```

Try adding a hyphen (-) before the @. It's quite possible that Razor thinks it's an e-mail address and leaving it alone!

Comment: I tried that. In the HTML source in my browser, the id is simply "label@Model.Id"

Answer (score 2):

Just adding another option as this is what worked for me when trying to concat string and model value as id in an @html.ActionLink and also for the text value. I needed to use string.Concat. Don't know if this is bad from a performance point of view.

```
  @Html.ActionLink(string.Concat("View all (", @Model.FooCount, ")"),
        //actionName        
        "SeeAllFoos",
        //ControllerName
        "Foo",
        // routeValues
        new { FooId = @Model.Foo.id },
        //htmlAttributes
        new { @class = "btn btn-success", onclick = "ShowProgress();",
        id = string.Concat("Foo",@Model.Foo.id.ToString()) })
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need to do.

```
id="label_@Model.Id"
```

Underscore(_) is required.For me passing id without Underscore made an issue. Happy conding.

Answer (score 0):

```
id="@("label")@Model.Id"
```

---

Adding underscore(_) `id="label_@Model.Id"` or hyphen (-) `id="label-@Model.Id"` to separate could also help. Have a great day!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.