# In razor views, how can I have a control such as <span id='cat@MYID' />?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a loop, and I want each id to be fixed string + id.

Any ideas?

`<span id='cat@MYID' />` does not work

Comment: Check out [ASP.NET MVC3 Razor Concatenation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702957/asp-net-mvc3-razor-concatenation)

Comment: What is the result of what you tried and what were you expecting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this ([explicit code nugget](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/16/asp-net-mvc-3-implicit-and-explicit-code-nuggets-with-razor.aspx)):

```
<span id='cat@(MYID)' />
```

Comment: Thanks, worked great. Felt odd to put the brackets after the @ =)

Answer (score 2):

```
@string.Format("cat{0}", MYID)
```