# Razor variable in string not rendering properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    int controlWidth=250;
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.studentFirstName, new { style = "width:@(controlWidth)px;" })
```

this code renders as

```
            <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Student First Name field is required." id="studentFirstName" name="studentFirstName" style="width:@(controlWidth)px;" type="text" value="" />
```

understandably, I want it to render as

```
            <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Student First Name field is required." id="studentFirstName" name="studentFirstName" style="width:250px;" type="text" value="" />
```

I've seen posts like [ASP.NET MVC Razor Concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702957/asp-net-mvc3-razor-concatenation) that suggest this approach is right. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can do that. Inline templates can only be used inside HTML like `<li style="@(controlWidth)">` or if your method supports inline template. See  http://vibrantcode.com/blog/2010/8/2/inside-razor-part-3-templates.html/ on how to write a method that supports inline template.

Comment: I'm beginning to see. Are you saying razor variables work in some areas but not in style parameters?

Comment: Yes it can work with methods that support inline template i.e. a method takes `Func<int, object> template` as argument & calls it just like what the author is doing in above post. But I don't see this is possible with C# properties and ofcourse style is property here. It is commonly used as html encoded expression like `<span>@model.Message</span>`.

Comment: zeeshan, what about this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702957/asp-net-mvc3-razor-concatenation ? I can't believe all the posters are lying that <li id="item_@(item.TheItemId)"> worked for them. The answer has a +42

Comment: Here `id` is not .NET property but attribute of `<li>` tag