# How to insert text directly before declaring razor?

Tags: razor

I want to type some text directly before declaring razor i.e. "TEXT@Model.Name"
but when the @ is that close to text it turns the whole statement into text.

Ive also tried "@TEXTModel.Name" but that doesnt work either

anyone know how to do it?

THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the variable with braces, like so:

```
TEXT@(Model.Name)
```

This should work. More help can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702957/asp-net-mvc-razor-concatenation). I hope this helps.