# Accordion Grouping using Dynamic Id

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, accordion, razorengine

I have a nested accordion. In the below piece of code I want to set a dynamic ID to the scheduleAccordion_. Unfortunately I cannot take any Model value (Model.ID) and append to it. How can I create a dynamic ID using dynamic variable in foreach or so?

```
<div class=" container-fluid" id="divpartialschedule">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="box box-solid">
            <div class="box-body">
                <div class="box-group" id="scheduleAccordion_@Model.ID">
                    @foreach (var scheItem in Model.Schedules)
                    {
                        <div class="panel box ">
                            <div class="box-header with-border" style="background-color: darkgrey">
                                <h4 class="box-title">
                                    <a class="collapsed" aria-expanded="false" href="#collapseSchedule_@scheItem.MXP_TemplateID" data-toggle="collapse" style="color:black" data-parent="#scheduleAccordion">
                                        @scheItem.ScheduleName
                                    </a>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add brackets

```
<div class="box-group" id="scheduleAccordion_@(Model.ID)">
```

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702957/asp-net-mvc-razor-concatenation)